# Booting from LVM partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, lvm

I screwed up when I installed my machine awhile back and put the `/` partition (including `/boot`) into the LVM.  While the machine will eventually boot, it won't boot non-interactively.  For whatever reason I end up in the `initramfs` prompt.  I do an `ls /dev/mapper` and eventually (10 minutes or so) the correct LVM partition shows up and I type `exit` and the machine boots normally.

Any way to solve this without having to redo the whole disk?

Comment: Figure out why it is taking 10 minutes for it to show up.  A separate /boot partition wouldn't help if it still isn't showing up when it should.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any space outside of the LVM? (A Windows partition, say?) If so, you could shrink it by a small amount (500MiB should be plenty, but in a pinch, even 100MiB might be OK) and create a `/boot` partition in that space. If not, you may need to shrink your LVM partition, which is unfortunately a bit awkward. [This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-resizing-partitions-2/index.html) I wrote a while ago covers the basics of doing this.